New latex symbols : 4 curve option in calculus
I'm working on some Calculus notes for a class I'm teaching, and I'm at the point where we study the curves and use the first and second derivative to trace the functions. For my table, I need 4 new symbols and I can't figure out what to use. Here's what it should look like.

I've used \nearrow and \searrow and \cup and \cap to represent the first and second derivatives influence, and I'm looking for symbols that somehow combine those symbols to have a better idea of how to draw the function in the end.
I know it's possible to create a Tikz symbol, from what I've seen here,it could work. The problem is I don't know how to draw the shapes I want in tikz, I've tried, but I can't seem to get it right.
Any ideas ? Thanks !

Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

To combine symbols representing the influence of the first and second derivatives in your table, you can use TikZ to draw custom symbols. Specifically, we can define custom commands using TikZ to represent the following:

\vexup: A convex curve going upwards.
\vexdown: A convex curve going downwards.
\aveup: A concave curve going upwards.
\avedown: A concave curve going downwards.

\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

% Importing tabularray for creating tables with booktabs
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

% Convex up
\newcommand{\vexup}{\tikz[
    baseline=(current bounding box.center) % Ensures the symbol is aligned with text
    ]{\draw (0,0) to [bend right] (0.5,0.5);}}

% Convex down
\newcommand{\vexdown}{\tikz[
    baseline=(current bounding box.center)
    ]{\draw (0,0) to [bend right] (0.5,-0.5);}}

% Concave up
\newcommand{\aveup}{\tikz[
    baseline=(current bounding box.center)
    ]{\draw (0,0) to [bend left] (0.5,0.5);}}

% Concave down
\newcommand{\avedown}{\tikz[
    baseline=(current bounding box.center)
    ]{\draw (0,0) to [bend left] (0.5,-0.5);}}

\begin{document}

% Table with 8 columns, centered text
\begin{tblr}{|*{8}{Q[c,m]|}}
\midrule
$f(x)$ & \aveup & max \newline 0 & \avedown & p.i.\newline -4 &
\vexdown & min \newline -8 & \vexup \\
\midrule
\end{tblr}

\end{document}



This works great ! Thank you. It's exactly the type of thing I had in mind, but I didn't know how to curve it, I could only do straight lines.

You could use the \manquartercircle symbol from the manfnt package:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{manfnt}

\begin{document}

\manquartercircle

\manrotatedquartercircle

\rotatebox[origin = c]{-90}{\manquartercircle}

\rotatebox{90}{\manrotatedquartercircle}

\end{document}



Thank you ! Never knew this symbol existed. It's a little small for what I want to do, so I will define it with Tikz, but this is a good alternative to know.

@tremblay You can resize the by changing the font size, e.g. {\Huge\manquartercircle}

True ! I was just trying not to overcrowd my code since it's already pretty dense... ! Thanks again !

@tremblay You're welcome!
